# How to separate a file into parts by delimiter

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing

I have a text file as follows:

```
aaaa 
bbbb
----  
cccc
----  
dddd
```

How can I use `----` as delimiter and take out for example dddd or cccc? By take out I mean run a command and get "dddd" if my input indicates I want the 3rd field of the whole file. It seems that `awk` or `cut` operates on only one line, so I couldn't think of any way to do this with these commands.

Comment: `awk` operates on *records* - by default the record separator (`RS`) is newline but you can set it to another value

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain a little more about what you want to do.  What do you mean by "take out"?  It'd be helpful to know what you'd like the result to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed and csplit to do this.

```
sed -i.bak 's/----/-/g' file && csplit --suppress-matched file '/-/' '{*}'
```

- `sed` will replace the "----" with a single "-" in file (and create a backup just in case)
- `csplit` will then split the file based on the single "-" and output multiple files [e.g. xx00, xx01 etc.]

EDIT: Thanks @AdminBee for pointing out the typo. removed the extra "file" from the command.

Comment: Are you sure the first `file` statement after `-i.bak` is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# split-textfile-by-first-line.sh

# split a text file by delimiter lines.
# the delimiter lines are included
# as first lines of the output files.

# removing the delimiter line
# would require patching
# the arguments for tail and head.

# (c) Milan Hauth, MIT License

set -eu

input_file="$1"
first_line="$2"

input_size=$(stat -c%s "$input_file")

start=
while read match; do
    # get the byte offset of match
    end=${match%%:*}
    if [ "$end" = "-1" ]; then
        # last match. set end to end of file
        end=$input_size
        if [ -z "$start" ]; then
            echo "error: first_line was not found in input_file"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    if [ -n "$start" ]; then
        output_file="$input_file".$start-to-$end
        cat "$input_file" |
            tail -c +$start |
            head -c $((end - start)) \
            >"$output_file"
        echo done "$output_file"
    fi
    start=$end
done < <(
    grep -bxF "$first_line" "$input_file"
    echo -1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Reading linewise:*

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @a; @a.push: $_ unless m/"----"/; END .say for @a[2];'  file
cccc

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @a; @a.push: $_ unless m/"----"/; END .say for @a[3];'  file
dddd
```

*Read file all-at-once:*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'slurp.split(/ "\n" | "----" /, :skip-empty).[2].put;'  file
cccc

~$ raku -e 'slurp.split(/ "\n" | "----" /, :skip-empty).[3].put;'  file
dddd
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. It features high-level Unicode support built in. Above, you can pull out the zero-indexed line of your choice, either the 3rd desired line (zero-index == 2) or the 4th desired line (zero-index == 3).

Sample Input:

```
aaaa
bbbb
----
cccc
----
dddd
```

---

*ADDENDUM:  Using Raku's `lines` routine (reads lazily):*

```perl
~$ raku -e '.[2].put if .chars for lines.map: *.split("----", :skip-empty);'  file
cccc

~$ raku -e '.[3].put if .chars for lines.map: *.split("----", :skip-empty);'  file
dddd
```

https://raku.org